# Operator overload - [Error] ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Edit: So I cleared to code up (removing code that works as intended) as requested in comments and tried running it, and it seems to work fine now..

Im trying to create a new vector with help of overloading. Although I'm getting an error when trying to compile:

```
[Error] ld returned 1 exit status
```

Below is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Matrix
{
public:


    Matrix(int row, int col, const double data[]){
    matrixarr.resize(row,vector<double>(col));
        for (int i = 0; i <matrixarr.size();i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < matrixarr[i].size();j++){
                matrixarr[i][j]= data[i+j];
            };
        };
    };

    Matrix &operator=(Matrix v)  {
    matrixarr.resize(v.matrixarr.size(),vector<double>(v.matrixarr[1].size()));
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i <matrixarr.size();i++){
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < matrixarr[i].size();j++){
                matrixarr[i][j]= v.matrixarr[i][j];
            };
        };
        return *this;
    };  

    ~Matrix()
    {
        matrixarr.clear();
    };


private:

    vector<vector<double> > matrixarr;

    friend Matrix operator *(const Matrix &src, const int x) {
    Matrix TEMP = src;
        for (int i = 0; i < TEMP.matrixarr.size();i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < TEMP.matrixarr[i].size();j++){
                TEMP.matrixarr[i][j]= src.matrixarr[i][j]*x;
            };
        };
    return TEMP;
    };
};

int main() {  
    double data2[] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
    Matrix m1(3, 2, data2);
    Matrix m4 = m1 * 2;

};
```

Any idea what is causing this error? Thanks!

Comment: The idea is written above the error you posted here.

Comment: @S.M. I'm not sure im getting your point. Mind clarifying?

Comment: You should post a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can get a better idea what is going on. It's hard to know because we can't compile the code you posted and reproduce the linker error.

Comment: @PhilipNelson, I cleared to code up to do an update, and now it seems to work.. Not sure why, but i guess your advice worked. Thanks!

Comment: @masan glad you got it!